# Show sources for tile values

Tags: civilization-6

With Civilization 6, it seems the bonus values which tiles can recieve are more complex than ever.

Not only is it affected by the terrain and features, but also things such as bonus resources, tile improvements, civics, leader/civlization bonus, adjacency bonus etc.

When I hover over the tile, I see just the calculated values, not their sources. Is there a way to get an advanced view that shows the exact composition of where the values comes from?

Comment: Do you mean sort of like the view you get when you are going to place a district?

Comment: @Joe Yeah, pretty much like that, but just a full breakdown of where all the values are coming from

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any way to see the calculation of the tile yields, but its generally not that hard to figure it out yourself.

There is a handy page [here](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Terrain_(Civ6)) that describes all the details on tile yields, but the general rule of thumb is:

- If it's green it gives more food
- If it's a hill it gives more production
- If it's got some other feature on it then it gets an additional gold/food/production bonus depending on the resource
- If it gives something that is not gold/food/production then its getting a bonus applied from either a natural wonder (always within one tile), a wonder (always in the city), or a religion/pantheon (you can check for this yourself.

That's pretty much all the possible inputs for tile yield calculations.